# Flutter console won't show errors

Tags: flutter

Flutter no longer shows any error message, I'm using android studio, but even if I start the program in console messages still won't appear. For example if mapping an object goes wrong, there will be no error shown in console, I'll have to find it my self

This is my main file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('Error'),
        ),
      );
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
  );

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  } catch (e) {}


  setupLocator();
  await SentryFlutter.init((SentryFlutterOptions options) {
    options.reportPackages = false;
    options.enableOutOfMemoryTracking = true;
    options.enableAppLifecycleBreadcrumbs = false;
    options.anrEnabled = true;
    options.debug = true;
    options.dsn ='';
    options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
  }, appRunner: () => runApp(MyApp(route: route,)));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String route;
  final bool isLoggedIn;

  MyApp({
    required this.route,
    required this.isLoggedIn,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GlobalBlocProviders(
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
      child: BlocListener<NotificationsBloc, NotificationsState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          final route = state.route;

          if (route == null) return;

          locator<NavigationService>().navigateTo(route);
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: TylerTheme,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? childWidget) {
            return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
              ),
              child: childWidget!,
            );
          },
          initialRoute: route,
          navigatorObservers: [
            StackedService.routeObserver,
            SentryNavigatorObserver()
          ],
          navigatorKey: StackedService.navigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: StackedRouter().onGenerateRoute,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Would be perfect if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to print the error via print method.

```
 try {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
      } catch (e) {
    print("Catch Exception is $e");
    }
```

Comment: Still won't show errors:/ only visual ones like renderbox overflow